# steam priceoverview SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, steam

What's wrong?

```
<script>
var url="http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2 M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear)";
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - priceoverview:1:10

Comment: The content returned from that URL is not valid JavaScript code.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2 M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear) 
When I open this link in browser I have JSON... Where is problem?

Comment: JSON is not JavaScript. A plain JSON object is not executable (or parseable) as JavaScript code, but that's what your code expects because you're using the URL as the source of a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That returns a plain json, rather than a jsonp. Unfortunately, Steam has cross origin stuff so ajax requests won't work, and they don't support jsonp. That means you won't be able to make the requests from the client--you have to get it server side.